# I want to connect rest api with my own <keyvaluepair> values

Tags: android, rest, dart, flutter

I can connect rest api on flutter but ı want to connect rest api with my own values. Here is my code :

```
var formContent = {

    "grant_type": "1",
    "branchcode": "1",
    "password": "1",
    "username": "1",
    "dbname": "1",
    "dbuser": "1",
    "dbpassword": "1",
    "dbtype": "1"

  };

Future<String> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("http://localhost:7070/api/v2/token"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    print(response.body);
  }
```

How can ı use my formContent on my getData() function ? I want to connect http://localhost:7070/api/v2/token with my form content and ı will get the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **post** data using an http request you have to use the post command

```
var postBody= json.encode(formContent);
var resopnse = await http.post(
         Uri.encodeFull("http://localhost:7070/api/v2/token"), 
         body: postBody, 
         headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
```

To import the json encoder, import the dart:convert package

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Comment: I have an another error like this : SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 44912

Comment: You don't have a connection to your server. Use Charles or a packet sniffer to see if you're packet is going out. Or first do a post using PostMan and see if it works. If it works then it's in your code, otherwise it's a connection issue.

Comment: @KaanKaramanoğlu The answer I gave is a solution to the problem you were asking for. What you're experiencing now is just connection issues

Comment: I try another programming language with my connection and values and it is okey but in flutter ı cannot run my code.